# Binding HTML 5 Audio src

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have this binding, which works partially.

```
  <audio controls="controls">
            <source data-bind="attr: { src: selectedItem().audioUrl}" type="video/mp4" />
   </audio>
```

It works, but when the audio is played, it only plays the first url that it is bound to.  So the same audio is played when it should be playing a different one.

Have tried: Setting Preload="none"

I can see the value changing in the debugger, so it is not that the binding is not getting updated.

I think the issue is that the url is actually downloaded as soon as the page loads, not when the user clicks the play button.  So the audio is not updated even if the src attribute is changed.

Is there a way to resolve this?

UPDATE:  I got this to work by subscribing to selectedItem and running this code:

```
 function changeAudio() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audioElement");
    if (audio) {
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause here - and I can't tell for certain because you haven't shown your view-model - is that you're attempting to subscribe to changes in the `selectedItem` observable, but in your binding you've bypassed the observable nature of that property and bound directly to the underlying value.

To be clear, when you bind to the underlying value Knockout will set this value when you call `ko.applyBindings`, but changes to the observable will not be picked up because the DOM element is not bound to the observable but to its initial value.

This is why, in your update, you've had to subscribe to changes in the `selectedItem` observable.

I'm not too certain on *what exactly* your solution involved, but here's my suggestion which would keep things in the MVVM pattern:

- declare another observable, `audioUrl`, at the same level as `selectedItem`
- add a *subscribe* handler to `selectedItem`
- in this *subscribe* handler, update the new `audioUrl` observable

So you'll end up with something like this:

```
self.audioUrl = ko.observable();
self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
self.selectedItem.subscribe(function(newVal) {
    self.audioUrl(newVal.audioUrl);
});
```

So now, whenever `selectedItem` is changed, the new `audioUrl` observable will be updated with the latest value. Consequently, any DOM elements bound to the new top-level `audioUrl` observable will dynamically update whenever `selectedItem` is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You could also build a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.audio = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        if (value) {
            element.src = value;
            element.load();
            element.play();
        }
    }
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9vpxcjws/